# Subscribe to iNav changes via ETF_INAV_VALUE key

Tags: bloomberg, etf

I'm using the Bloomberg API to subscribe to market data changes. While I manage to retrieve fields such as `OPT_GAMMA_MID_RT` or `OPT_DELTA_ASK_RT`, it seems I cannot retrieve the iNav for a given ETF (the code would be `ETF_INAV_VALUE`).

I can send a `ReferenceDataRequest` directly (using the ticker and the code `ETF_INAV_VALUE`) and correctly get the value, but I don't receive any feed regarding changes to the iNav value. I would like to avoid polling with `ReferenceDataRequest`...

The field is updated in my terminal but I am not made aware of it in my code even though I did subscribe.

Does this field need special handling compared to regular `ASK` / `BID` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ETF_INAV_VALUE` is not a real time field so it won't work (HELP HELP may have a workaround on this).

Alternatively, you can query the `EXCHANGE_TRADED_FUNDS_NAV_TKR_RT` field which will give you a ticker for the NAV. Then subscribing to the last price on that ticker should give you what you want (note that I haven't tried).

Comment: thanks for the swift and insightful reply, I'll try that ! I think you meant `EXCH_TRADED_FUNDS_INAV_TKR_RT` for the field though.